# Guice "Throwing Providers" : How to bind to a type with generics?

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

Using Guice 3.0, I try to inject a Provider that can throw specific checked exceptions. So I use the [Throwing Providers extension](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ThrowingProviders).

I created an interface for the Provider :

```
public interface IMyProvider<T> extends CheckedProvider<T> 
{
    @Override
    T get() throws MyException;
}
```

And its implementation :

```
public class MyProvider implements IMyProvider<List<SomeType>> 
{
    @Override
    public List<SomeType> get() throws MyException                        
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

I use the @Inject annotation on the object where I want to inject the Provider :

```
@Inject
public SomeConstructor(IMyProvider<List<SomeType>> myProvider)
{
    //...
}
```

Now, my problem is : *how to bind this Provider*?

Since generics are used, I though about using `TypeLiteral` :

```
bind(MyProvider.class);
ThrowingProviderBinder.create(binder())
                      .bind(IMyProvider.class, new TypeLiteral<List<SomeType>>(){})
                      .to(MyProvider.class);
```

But it seems `TypeLiteral` is not a valid argument for this bind() method.

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE :**

I found a workaround. By creating a class that extends `ArrayList<SomeType>`, I'm able to bind the Provider :

```
public class SomeTypeList extends ArrayList<SomeType>
```

and

```
bind(MyProvider.class);
ThrowingProviderBinder.create(binder())
                      .bind(IMyProvider.class, SomeTypeList.class)
                      .to(MyProvider.class);
```

But it would be easier if that `SomeTypeList` class wouldn't be required!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a `Type` instance, which `TypeLiteral` does not natively implement.

I haven't worked with this directly, but Guice does provide a [`Types`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/util/Types.html#newParameterizedType%28java.lang.reflect.Type,%20java.lang.reflect.Type...%29) class, and there is also a method [`TypeLiteral.getType`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html#getType%28%29). Try one of the following:

- `Types.listOf(SomeType.class)`
- `Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, SomeType.class)`
- `(new TypeLiteral<List<SomeType>>() {}).getType()`

My preference is the first, which would look like this:

```
ThrowingProviderBinder
    .create(binder())
    .bind(IMyProvider.class, Types.listOf(SomeType.class))
    .to(MyProvider.class);
```

Comment: All of them work! With one small change : "(new TypeLiteral<List<SomeType.class>>() {}).getType()" should be "(new TypeLiteral<List<SomeType>>() {}).getType()". Thank you Jeff!

Comment: @electrotype Whoops! Thanks for catching that. Answer updated. Glad to help!